# Error using HoughCircles with 3-channel input

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

Before detecting circles, I am replacing the `red` channel with the `green` channel. After replacing the channel, I pass it through a blur filter and then do a Hough transform to detect circles. But as I do this, I get a crappy error message:

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (!_image.empty() && _image.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) && (_image.isMat() || 

_image.isUMat())) in HoughCircles, file /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp, line 1659
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "circle_light.py", line 44, in <module>
    param1=param1,param2=param2,minRadius=minRadius,maxRadius=maxRadius)

cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp:1659: error: (-215) !_image.empty() 

&& _image.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()) in function HoughCircles
```

I could not make any sense from it and thus could not understand what I could be doing incorrectly. Here is the snippet to what I did.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("images/{}".format("img.png"), 1)

b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
img = cv2.merge([b,g,g])
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)

minDist = 11
param1 = 20
param2 = 20
minRadius = 10
maxRadius = 20

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(
    img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist,
    param1=param1, param2=param2, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius
)
```

The error happens when I call `HoughCircles` function. What is it that I might be doing incorrectly?

Comment: In case you are interested, I explain the error message in my answer and I provide a little bit more of information on why `cv2.HoughCircles()` uses single-channel inputs. The answer is long, but it is your fault: your question made me curious :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About interpreting the error. It comes from [hough.cpp#L1659](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L1659):

```
CV_Assert(!_image.empty() && _image.type() == CV_8UC1 && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()));
```

Breaking it down, all the following conditions have to be true:

- `!_image.empty()`: the input image should not be empty;
- `_image.type() == CV_8UC1`: the input image must be `8U` (8-bit unsigned, `np.uint8`) and `C1` (single-channel);
- `_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()`: check if the input is `Mat` or `UMat` (in Python, it has to be a numpy array);

Regarding your specific error message (`error: (-215) !_image.empty() && _image.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat())`):

- The error code (-215) comes from [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp#L115): it is the generic `CV_StsAssert`;
- And then these numbers: they represent `CV_8UC1`. Are you curious to know why? You should :) Here we go:

  1. `CV_8UC1`
  2. `CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U,1)` :: from [`#define CV_8UC1 CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U,1)`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h#L86)
  3. `CV_MAKETYPE(0,1)` :: from [`#define CV_8U 0`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h#L71)
  4. `(CV_MAT_DEPTH(0) + (((1)-1) << CV_CN_SHIFT))` :: from [`#define CV_MAKETYPE(depth,cn) (CV_MAT_DEPTH(depth) + (((cn)-1) << CV_CN_SHIFT))`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h#L83)
  5. `(((0) & CV_MAT_DEPTH_MASK) + (((1)-1) << CV_CN_SHIFT))` :: from [`#define CV_MAT_DEPTH(flags) ((flags) & CV_MAT_DEPTH_MASK)`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h#L81)
  6. `(((0) & (CV_DEPTH_MAX - 1)) + (((1)-1) << CV_CN_SHIFT))` :: from [`#define CV_MAT_DEPTH_MASK (CV_DEPTH_MAX - 1)`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h#L80)
  7. `(((0) & ((1 << CV_CN_SHIFT) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << CV_CN_SHIFT))` :: from [`#define CV_DEPTH_MAX (1 << CV_CN_SHIFT)`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h#L69)
  8. `(((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3))` :: from [`#define CV_CN_SHIFT 3`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h#L68)

---

I'll try to complement [@Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621)'s answer, simply because I was curious and I want to share :)

If you look at the documentation, [`cv2.HoughCircle()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d) is part of the [imgproc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/dbd/group__imgproc.html) module (under the [Feature Detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html) "*submodule*"). The documentation says that the only implemented method is the [HOUGH_GRADIENT](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/dbd/group__imgproc.html#gga073687a5b96ac7a3ab5802eb5510fe65ab1bf00a90864db34b2f72fa76389931d) (aka [21HT](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d0/de3/citelist.html#CITEREF_Yuen90), i.e., Two stage Hough Transform), and they point out to the reference paper "[Comparative study of Hough Transform methods for circle finding](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/026288569090059E)" (1990) :). If you cannot access because of the paywall, you can access the [1989's version for free](http://www.bmva.org/bmvc/1989/avc-89-029.pdf)). In the paper, the authors comment:

> The HT method of shape analysis uses a constraint equation relating points in a feature space to possible parameter values of the searched for shape. For each
>   feature point, **invariably edge points**, votes are accumulated for all parameter combinations which satisfy the constraint. [...]

Later, they write:

> **If edge direction information is available**, then one way to reduce the storage and computational demands of circle finding is to decompose the problem into two
>   stages [...]

Therefore, if you want to stick to the 21HT, you basically need both edges and edge direction information. For instance, you could get the edge direction information via `Sobel` (e.g., `dx` and `dy`), and use these already computed `dx` and `dy` to get the edges using `Canny`. In fact, this is what the OpenCV implementation does. If you navigate to [`modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp), you can see the Sobel+Sobel+Canny operations [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L1569-L1571).

So, what? Well, it means that if you have another method (or you want to propose a new one, why not?) that is able to return edges and edge direction information that are better suited for your case (maybe the *colors* have a different meaning in your case), then you can just replace these 3 lines (Sobel+Sobel+Canny) with your method and re-use the rest of the implementation (cool, huh?). If you are feeling inspired :), you can take a look at "[A Short History of Color Edge Detection](http://ai.stanford.edu/~ruzon/compass/color.html)" and start from there.

Then, why do we need single-channel inputs? Well, basically because we need edges, and they are usually represented as *single-channel images*. In addition, the [implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L1080-L1193) only supports single-channel edges and edge direction information so far. However, most of these concepts could be extended to multi-channel inputs. I think that, because there are no generic solutions (probably these concepts change in a case-by-case basis) and very few people would benefit from, no one bothered to provide any implementation so far.

Sorry for the long answer. I know the TL;DR "the method requires single-channel input" is enough. I got curious and wanted to share =]

Answer (score 6):

You can only call `cv2.HoughCircles()` on a single-channel (greyscale) image, your image has 3 channels.

[Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d).

Comment: What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: I guess people normally find edges first, which yields a greyscale image, then look for edges that make up circles.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It is important to note that the `cv2.HoughCircle()` will, internally, apply Sobel and Canny to get the edges and edge information needed by the 21HT algorithm. I provide some details (to complement your answer) on the second part of my answer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Berriel I'm always happy to learn something new - so thank you.