# HOGDescriptor returns error: img.type() == 0 || img.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((3)-1) << 3)) in function cv::HOGDescriptor::computeGradient

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use HOGDescriptor on my dataset images, so I can train a pytorch neural net.

these are image transformations:

```
train_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize([32,32]),
                                          transforms.Grayscale(),
                                       transforms.ToTensor(),])
train_data = datasets.ImageFolder(datadir,
                transform=train_transforms)
```

this is my code for HOG:

```
nbins = 9  # broj binova
cell_size = (2, 2)  # broj piksela po celiji
block_size = (2, 2)  # broj celija po bloku


    for im,l in train_data:
        im = im.numpy()
        hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor(_winSize=(im.shape[1] // cell_size[1] * cell_size[1],
                                          im.shape[0] // cell_size[0] * cell_size[0]),
                                _blockSize=(block_size[1] * cell_size[1],
                                            block_size[0] * cell_size[0]),
                                _blockStride=(cell_size[1], cell_size[0]),
                                _cellSize=(cell_size[1], cell_size[0]),
                                _nbins=nbins)


        im=hog.compute(im)
```

I have been getting this error:

```
img.type() == 0 || img.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((3)-1) << 3)) in function cv::HOGDescriptor::computeGradient
```

Comment: If you are curious about these numbers, I did a _similar_ breakdown [once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54382732/4228275) :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your image to grayscale.
As the documentation shows: [link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ocl/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html?highlight=hogdescriptor#void%20ocl::HOGDescriptor::detect(const%20oclMat&%20img,%20vector%3CPoint%3E&%20found_locations,%20double%20hit_threshold,%20Size%20win_stride,%20Size%20padding))

`img – Source image. CV_8UC1 and CV_8UC4 types are supported for now.`

you can check you image type with

```
# reading image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('path.jpg', 0)
print(img.dtype) # returns dtype('uint8')
img.shape # returns (h, w) if it returns (h, w, 3) then it is not grayscale
```

Answer (score 0):

That means that your image has to be one channel and type CV_8U or CV_8UC3 - 1 or 3 channel image with unsigned char values. Check what type is in your image.